# What is the parameter type for a generic function parameter when called from a base class with 'this'?

Tags: c#, inheritance, generic-function

Confusing question, I know.  Given the following:

```
    class Test
    {
        public static void GenericFunc<T>(T SomeType)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("typeof(T): " + typeof(T).Name);
            System.Console.WriteLine("SomeType.GetType(): " + SomeType.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    public class BaseType
    {
        public void RunTest() { Test.GenericFunc(this); }
    }

    public class DerivedType : BaseType { }
```

The following code produces interesting output:

```
    DerivedType Derived = new DerivedType();
    Derived.RunTest();

    // output:
    // typeof(T): BaseType
    // SomeType.GetType(): DerivedType
```

However, this behaves as I would expect:

```
    Test.GenericFunc(new Derived());

    // output:
    // typeof(T): DerivedType
    // SomeType.GetType(): DerivedType
```

Can anyone help me understand the mechanism here that's causing T to be evaluated as BaseType in the first case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is what Java avoids by having type-erasure in generic instantiations...

Comment: @antlersoft: The only thing Java 'avoids' is type safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public void RunTest() { Test.GenericFunc(this); }
}
```

Is basically equivalent to:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public void RunTest() { Test.GenericFunc<BaseType>(this); }
}
```

Therefore the `GenericFunc` gets instatiated at compile time with `T = BaseType`. However the `this` object you are passing in at runtime is the derived type which you get by `SomeType.GetType()`.

In the second case the compiler infers the type as `DerivedType` directly from the usage and therefore `GenericFunc` gets instatiated with `T = DerivedType`.

Comment: Just goes to show how long I've been away from C++.  I know that generics are evaluated at compile time, but for some reason there I got it in my head that it was all happening at run time.  Embarrassing.  Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 14):

Unless the "dynamic" type is involved, overload resolution and type inference are performed **at compile time**, not **at run time**.

When overload resolution sees `Test.GenericFunc(this);` it must deduce the generic type argument that corresponds to the missing generic type parameter. That is an easy problem; it uses the **compile time** type of `this`, and inside a method of `BaseType`, clearly the **compile time** type of `this` is always `BaseType`.

Therefore overload resolution assumes that you intended to call `Test.GenericFunc<BaseType>(this)`.

If you intend this to be worked out a runtime, you can do that in C# 4. Just say `Test.GenericFunc((dynamic)this)`.  **That will start the overload resolution engine again at runtime, which will then pretend that you had cast `this` to its runtime type back at compile time.**

Yes, that is every bit as expensive as it sounds. **If you want semantic analysis at runtime then we're going to have to run a semantic analyzer at runtime.**

Comment: I wasn't aware of the dynamic keyword in C# 4.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you much for this.  Solved my problem of the compile time (this) reference.